# SQLite error with omniauth and twitter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter, omniauth

I am using omniauth to let users sign in with Facebook and Twitter accounts in a Ruby on Rails application. As Twitter `request.env["omniauth.auth"]` does not give the account's email I construct it (the email cannot be NULL in the database). I have this piece of code:

```
if params[:provider] == 'facebook'
              email = omniauth[:info]["email"]
elsif params[:provider] == 'twitter'
              email = omniauth[:info]["name"] + '@example.com'
end
user = User.new(:email => email)
```

If I sign in with Facebook account it works perfect. But if I try with Twitter account the applicacion gives me this error:

```
SQLite3::ConstraintException: users.email may not be NULL [SQL query]
```

I checked if the email was NULL several times in case it was badly constructed or something, but is not NULL. `omniauth-twitter` and `omniauth-facebook` gems are installed.
Does anyone know why?
Let me know if you need more code or information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't like any of theses approaches to be honest. A name isn't a unique constraint and a Twitter user can change his nickname at any time. What would happen if a user changed his nickname? Would he no longer be able to access his account? And what if another person changed his nickname to the now available nickname? Would he be able to access the other user's account?

Two better solutions would be either:

1. Follow [Ryan Bates's approach](http://railscasts.com/episodes/236-omniauth-part-2) and redirect the user to a form where he can type his email. Or
2. Override Devise's method [email_required?](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/models/validatable.rb#L57). Something like:

   ```
   # user.rb
   def email_required?
     authentications.empty?
   end
   ```

   This way you wouldn't introduce an extra step into the login process.

Comment: I tried _Ryan Bate's approach_ but I get the same result. I think I'm missing something somewhere and I can't see it. I will try it again and I'll tell you my results.

Comment: I finally managed to log in with twitter account and I'm trying to redirect so that the user types his email. I prefer that solution rather than the other one too :) thank you both

Answer (score 0):

Twitter does not send back the e-mail address as part of the OAuth handshake.  You will have to either generate one or send them to another registration page, temporarily storing their Twitter authorization info to pre-populate the registration fields.

It looks like you are attempting to generate an e-mail address based on the user's name.  Twitter send this back in the form of "FirstName LastName", so if you have any e-mail address validations, they will not accept an e-mail address in the form of "FirstName LastName@someaddress.com".  Might I suggest that you use `"#{omniauth[:info][:nickname]}@twitter.com"` instead?  This way, you're also protected against duplicate e-mail addresses, since Twitter usernames are unique.